# Why is my text overflowing its div on Safari but not Chrome?

Tags: css, overflow, word-wrap

Having a weird CSS problem with Safari - I can't seem to get the text to wrap within its div - no problem with the same CSS code in Chrome or Firefox.

Please see attached image for illustration of the problem.

Here is my CSS code for the div:

```
#wiki{
display: none;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FCFCFC;
border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
border-radius: 10px;
margin-top: 5px;
padding: 10px;
line-height: 2.3em;
font-size: 16px;
width: 95%;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
box-sizing: border-box; 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

[image]

Comment: try word-break:break-all property.

Comment: have you used #wiki in a div? if yes trying overflow: hidden;

Comment: Black-Hole: Tried this, but it hides the content rather than wrapping it, which is no good

Comment: Gunaseelan: I can't see how this would help me solve the issue highlighted above.. can you elaborate?

Comment: Suresh: Tried it, but has no effect on the problem :-(

Comment: Is this the latest version of Safari? If it's older, such as the most recent one for Windows (over 2 years old), that might explain the differences with the newest Chrome.